# dynamical plot using plot_ly from R-plotly package

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I am using shiny and `plot_ly` to plot a `data frame`.

**The Goal**: to implement a dynamical plot depending on the choice of users in `GUI`.

Consider the following `data.table` named `pl.d`

```
Group   OS  NP  own.OS  own.SCR  HY9    WS8
A       34  54    27      76     56     82
B       15  45    0       84     89     48
C        0  36    7       92     91     22
```

in the `server.R` I used

```
 plot_ly(pl.d, x = ~Group, y = ~OS, type = 'bar', name = "OS" ) %>% 
layout(showlegend = TRUE)
```

The user should be able to expand the plot in the way that y could be an arbitrary choice of `c(OS, NP, own.OS, own.SCR,    HY9,    WS8)`. 
One not smart possible approach is to expand the `plot_ly` function with

```
    if (input$choice of user =="NP"){
add_trace(y = ~NP, name = "NP") 
}
```

and `if conditions`and so on.

Is there any smart possibility to write an smart dynamical code to do that?

It has not to do with "NP". I mean `plot_ly` or `add_trace` should be in principle able to show one or many of `c(OS,   NP, own.OS, own.SCR,HY9,WS8)`.
I can write it as follows:

```
  plot_ly(pl.d, x = ~Group, y = ~OS, type = 'bar', name = "OS" ) %>% 
add_trace(y = ~NP, name = "NP") %>% 
add_trace(y = ~own.OS, name = "own.OS") %>% 
add_trace(y = ~own.SCR, name = "own.SCR") %>% 
add_trace(y = ~HY9, name = "HY9") %>% 
add_trace(y = ~WS8, name = "WS8")%>% 
layout(showlegend = TRUE)
```

**Problem**: If you omit one of `c(OS,  NP, own.OS, own.SCR,HY9,WS8)` you get an error!

One possible solution: to split the data frame into vectors! Using `melt` function makes it possible, however I do not get vectors just another shape of data table! Please take into account my outgoing point is `pl.d` and **not** `data.frame(Group =c(...), ....)`!
So, I tried the following

```
pl.d<-data.frame(Group =melt(setDT(d.plot), id.var = 'Group ')[,1],
    model=melt(setDT(d.plot), id.var = 'Group ')[,2],
    value=melt(setDT(d.plot), id.var = 'Group ')[,3])
```

and then,

```
  plot_ly(pl.d, x = ~Group, y = ~value, type = 'bar', color= ~model ) %>% 
add_trace(y = ~value, name = "NP")
```

However, I do not get for example the bars belonging to A close to each other.

**Addendum:** My mistake was, that I used `color= ~model` I had to use `color=~Variable as mentioned in the answer! BUT why? I set it in my data frame as`model`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are on the right track. You can use `melt` and `filter` to create a dataframe with the desired column names, like the following code.

```
data = data.frame(Group = c("a","b","c"),os = c(1,2,3),np = c(4,5,6), ws = c(7,8,9))

plot_cols = function(data, column_names = colnames(data)){
  data%>%
    melt()%>%
    filter(variable %in% column_names) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~Group,y = ~value,color = ~variable,type = "bar")
}
```

You can plot all columns by calling `plot_cols(data)` or any select column like `plot_cols(data,"os")` or `plot_cols(data,c("os","ws"))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I response to you in the question!

Comment: thanks a lot. My fault was, that I used color=~ model, I had to use, as you said ~variable!  But why?

Comment: Take a look at the output of `data %>% melt()` by default, it creates a column called variable and a column called value.